# How do I integrate $\int f(x) dx = \int \frac{e^{g(x)}}{g'(x)}\, dx$?

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I am developing a monetary economics model with an exponential growth term embedded within an exponential function. When I solve the equation, I wind up either with everything cancelling out, or with $\int f(x) dx = \int \frac{e^{g(x)}}{g'(x)} dx$.

Life would be *so* much easier, if it were $\displaystyle\int e^{g(x)}g'(x)\, dx$, but, sadly, $g'(x)$ winds up in the denominator.

Any suggestions, even just hints, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is hard to parse.  Do you mean $\int \frac {e^{g(x)}}{g'(x)} \,dx$?

Comment: Assuming I am reading it correctly (far from clear), I expect that you will need to phrase the answer in terms of the [Exponential Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) or such.

Comment: I would recommend that you type up the larger problem. You might be simplifying down to this integral incorrectly, or maybe there's a hidden assumption you're making.

Comment: The equation that I am dealing with looks like the one in my subject line and in Lulu's comment 1 above.

The starting point is:

$\int e^{-r{e^{{\rho}t}}t} dt$

Comment: Based on your starting point at least, it doesn't look like a nice closed form is going to exist: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+e%5E(-te%5Et)+dt

Comment: Brenton, thank you. I tried Wolfram Alpha and got the same result. However, I did not know if that was definitive. For example, I have tested different equations of the form $\int e^u u'_t dt$, where $\mathbf u$ is a relatively complex formula, and Wolfram Alpha has choked on that.

Answer (score 0):

If the starting problem is
$$I=\int e^{-r\, e^{\,\rho \, t}} \,dt$$ let 
$$r\, e^{\,\rho \, t}=x \implies t=\frac{1}{\rho}{\log \left(\frac{x}{r}\right)}\implies dt=\frac{dx}{\rho  x}$$
$$I=\frac{1}{\rho}\int \frac{e^{-x}}{ x}\,dx=\frac{1}{\rho}\text{Ei}(-x)$$ where appears the exponential integral function already mentioned by lulu. Back to $t$
$$I=\frac{1}{\rho}\text{Ei}\left(-r\, e^{\,\rho\,  t}\right)$$

However, I do not see the connection with the problem in title.

Comment: Thank you for this, however my starting point is:

$\int e^{-r{e^{\rho t}}t} dt$

Comment: @Pecuniology. Sorry but I still do not see what you need. As asked in comments, could you provide the real problem from the start ?